# Using SELECT as column

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm using this query

```
SELECT
     fullname,
     (SELECT 
          count([ID]) FROM [SDT-DB].[dbo].[tbl_InfoBoard_UserLogs] 
          WHERE fullname = fullname AND user_did ='login') AS [Login],
     (SELECT 
          count([ID]) FROM [SDT-DB].[dbo].[tbl_InfoBoard_UserLogs] 
          WHERE fullname = fullname AND user_did ='message') AS [View Messageboard],
     (SELECT 
          count([ID]) FROM [SDT-DB].[dbo].[tbl_InfoBoard_UserLogs] 
          WHERE fullname = fullname AND user_did ='notification') AS [View Notification],
     count([ID]) AS Count
FROM [SDT-DB].[dbo].[tbl_InfoBoard_UserLogs]
GROUP BY fullname
```

it seems its returning all userlogs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT fullname,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_did = 'login' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Login],
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_did = 'message' AS [View Messageboard],
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_did = 'notification' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [View Notification],
       count([ID]) AS Count
FROM [SDT-DB].[dbo].[tbl_InfoBoard_UserLogs]
GROUP BY fullname;
```

Your logic doesn't work because you have no correlation clause.  You seem to *intend* to have one with `fullname = fullname`, but that just evaluates to true whenever `fullname` is not `NULL`.  But, the above is simpler.